# How do I generate random numbers from [0,1]?

Tags: python, random

I want to generate random numbers from [0,1].

```
import os

int.from_bytes(os.urandom(8), byteorder="big") / ((1 << 64) - 1)
```

The code above does not work in my python version.

Also

```
import random

random.random()
```

only generate random variables from [0,1) and does not include 1. I want it to be exactly [0,1] Any other ways to do this?

Comment: `random.uniform(0, 1)`?

Comment: @ajcr I read the documentation and it says for random.uniform: "The end-point value b may or may not be included in the range depending on floating-point rounding in the equation a + (b-a) * random()." So I'm not that sure if random.uniform is a good choice.

Comment: @Ralf17 But doesn't that mean that `float` cannot guarantee the inclusive/exclusiveness of exact boundaries because of its precision restrictions?

Comment: I want a guaranteed [0,1] generated solution. If this is possible.

Comment: Why not something like `(random.randint(0,10*6)*1.0 /10*6)` . It guarantess the inclusion of boundaries and is pretty simple to understand.

Comment: @Siddhant I tested (random.randint(0,10*6)*1.0 /10*6) and it is producing numbers out of the interval [0,1].

Comment: @Ralf17 use this `(random.randint(0,10**6)*1.0 /10**6)`  . What I wrote before wasn't right. It was multiplying 10 to 6 rather than rasing 10 to the power 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Python's [`random`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) module:

```
import random

# int
x = random.randint(0, 1)  # 0 or 1(both incl.)

# float excl. 1.0
x = random.random()  # float from [0,1)
```

or, as pointed out by @ajcr and described [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.uniform).:

```
# from [0.0, 1.0], but upper boundary not guaranteed
x = random.uniform(0, 1)
```

As `float`'s precision and rounding issues apply to all those methods, one could try to cheat and use the `decimal` module:

```
import decimal

def randfloat():
    decimal.getcontext().prec = 10  # 10 decimal points enough?!
    return decimal.Decimal(0) + decimal.Decimal(random.uniform(0, 1))
# this should include both boundaries as float gets close enough to 1 to make decimal round

>>> decimal.Decimal(0) + decimal.Decimal(0.99999999999)
Decimal('1.000000000')

# while uniform() apparently guarantees the inclusion of the lower boundary
```

Comment: I want to generate continuous variables or floats, random.randint(0, 1) only gives integers while random.random() works on [0,1) but not [0,1].

Comment: Hmm... what resolution do you need. Full floating point precision. You could go with sth. like `random.randint(0, 10**6) * 1.0 / 10**6`

Answer (score 0):

Tool you are searching for could be `random.uniform(0, 1)`